# Type level insert and retrieve a certain value on a Map in Scala

Tags: scala, type-level-computation

Given a (data structure that operates like a) `Map`. Is there a type level way of inserting to it? That is:

```
val myMap: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
val x: Int = 5
val y: Int = 99

val myMap2 = myMap + (x -> "e")
```

What I'm hoping for is that `myMap2` will have some type wherein I can safely do something like `myMap2.retrieve(x)` and have it compile and return `"e"`. But `myMap2.retrieve(y)` should not even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps) if your keys have different types:

```
import shapeless._

object _1 
object _2
object _3
object _4


//-------------Map definition starts here----------------
class StaticMap1[K, V]
trait StaticMap1Like {
  type M[T] <: StaticMap1[T, String]
  private def add[T]: M[T] = (new StaticMap1[T, String] {}).asInstanceOf[M[T]]

  implicit val __1 = add[_1.type] //add key to StaticMap1
  implicit val __2 = add[_2.type] //add key to StaticMap1
}
object StaticMap1 extends StaticMap1Like


val hm = HMap[StaticMap1](_1 -> "a", _2 -> "b") //add values
//-------------Map definition ends here-----------------

scala> hm.get(_1)
res0: Option[String] = Some(a)

scala> hm.get(_2)
res1: Option[String] = Some(b)

scala> hm.get(_3) //compile-time error
<console>:18: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: BiMapIS[shapeless.nat._3,V]
              hm.get(_3)
                    ^
```

And key insertion:

```
//----Adding element _3 -> "c" starts here--------------
class StaticMap2[K, V] extends StaticMap1[K, V]
trait StaticMap2Like extends StaticMap1Like {
  type M[T] <: StaticMap2[T, String]
  private def add[T] = new StaticMap2[T, String] {}.asInstanceOf[M[T]]
  implicit val __3 = add[_3.type] //add key to StaticMap2
}
object StaticMap2 extends StaticMap2Like

val hm2 = hm.asInstanceOf[HMap[StaticMap2]] + (_3 -> "c")
//----Adding element ends here---------------------------

scala> hm2.get(_3)
res6: Option[String] = Some(c)

scala> hm2.get(_2)
res7: Option[String] = Some(b)

scala> hm2.get(_1)
res8: Option[String] = Some(a)

scala> hm2.get(_4)
<console>:21: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: StaticMap2[_4.type,V]
          hm2.get(_4)
                 ^

scala> hm.get(_3) //old `hm` still working
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: StaticMap1[_3.type,V]
          hm.get(_3)
                ^
```

But:

- don't use Shapeless native `nat` here - it won't work as it can't distinguish `nat._1` from `nat._2` (at least for my version of Shapeless)
- adding element to а `Map` also wouldn't be so convinient, as user is gonna have to add an implicit for every new key

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use `myMap2.get(y)` you will get an `Option` of String for any y if it is an `Int`.
In case you try to use any other type, you will have a compilation exception. 
e.g.: `myMap2.get("y")` will throw a type mismatch.
So you can't compile if the key type is not the right one.